# Displaying 3D subsoil models in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, modelling

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to display a 3D subsoil model in ArcScene?

The data we will have will be exported from rockworks in point form and then we need to convert it to TINs. That's what we believe is the correct approach.

I have never done any extensive work in arcscene before and I couldn't find anything too helpful on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If your point data is in shapefile format, then in ArcToolbox under the 3D Analyst Toolbox you can interpolate your soil points with one of the Raster Interpolation tools.

You can then create a TIN from the raster layer using the Raster to TIN tool.

Comment: It's exported as an ascii (so terrible) but we have some script which converts to an shapefile - i will try this out thanks!!